# A script using pandas for web scraping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, web-scraping

I've been working on a script that reads in a .csv file with a list of websites all in the 1st column. I want to loop through and parse the HTML for every link in the website column of the .csv file the HTML tags are the same for every link. There are 200 rows, but when I run my code, I only get data for the last row of the column, so row (200) instead of (1-200). I believe the issue may stem from my for loop and my use of iterows but I'm not experienced enough in python/pandas.
'''

```
df = pd.read_csv('~/Documents/websites.csv', usecols=['website'], 
delimiter=',')
url = df['website']

df.dropna(subset=['website'])


data = []

df.to_csv(header=True, index=False, path_or_buf='/Users/Desktop/scraped_data.csv')

print(df)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
     website = row['website']
     response = requests.get(website)
     content = response.text

     

     soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
     result = soup.find('div',class_ = 'KeyStatisticsCard_support-card__fK7N2')
     

     tag1 = soup.find('span',class_ = 'KeyStatisticsCard_field-text__GtuGd')
     tag2 = soup.find('div',class_ = 'ant-col KeyStatisticsCard_field-info__gYdfV')
     tag3 = soup.find('a',class_ = 'KeyStatisticsCard_ellipsis__TE9tk')
     tag4 = soup.find('span',class_ = 'KeyStatisticsCard_ellipsis__TE9tk')

d = {'tag1':tag1.text,'tag2':tag2.text, 'tag3':tag3.text,
     'tag4':tag4.text if tag4 else None} 

data.append(d)

#convert to a pandas df
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

'''

Comment: Good catch, I just did the above and include both in the for loop, now i have the following error:

200 rows x 1 columns]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/movalles/Documents/Scraping/certik_scrape.py", line 45, in <module>
    d = {'audits':audits.text,'onboarded date':onboarded.text, 'website':website.text,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 1):

Try sliding the d={tag1.... and data.append(d) into the for loop. Because they aren't included in the loop you are only getting the most recent iteration of the loop.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     website = row['website']
     response = requests.get(website)
     content = response.text

     

     soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
     result = soup.find('div',class_ = 'KeyStatisticsCard_support- 
     card__fK7N2')
     

     tag1 = soup.find('span',class_ = 'KeyStatisticsCard_field-text__GtuGd')
     tag2 = soup.find('div',class_ = 'ant-col KeyStatisticsCard_field- 
     info__gYdfV')
     tag3 = soup.find('a',class_ = 'KeyStatisticsCard_ellipsis__TE9tk')
     tag4 = soup.find('span',class_ = 'KeyStatisticsCard_ellipsis__TE9tk')

     d = {'tag1':tag1.text,'tag2':tag2.text, 'tag3':tag3.text,
     'tag4':tag4.text if tag4 else None} 

     data.append(d)

#convert to a pandas df
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the indentation IT looks like both lines are outside of for loop.

```
d = {'tag1':tag1.text,'tag2':tag2.text, 'tag3':tag3.text,
         'tag4':tag4.text if tag4 else None} 
    
data.append(d)
```

So you put only the last entry in the list data. Regaring your error message you Can add a vérification if not none (to avoid to call the text attribut on none object which means than the class you were looking for is not existing on the URL)

```
    tag3 = soup.find('a',class_ = 'KeyStatisticsCard_ellipsis__TE9tk')
    tag4 = soup.find('span',class_ = 'KeyStatisticsCard_ellipsis__TE9tk')
    if tag1 is not none:
        tag1=tag1.text
    if tag2 is not none:
        tag2=tag2.text
    if tag3 is not none:
        tag3=tag3.text
    if tag4 is not none:
        tag4=tag4.text

    d = {'tag1':tag1,'tag2':tag2, 'tag3':tag3,
     'tag4':tag4 if tag4 else None} 

    data.append(d)

#convert to a pandas df
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```